# Microsoft Word 2010 - Changing Caption Text

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, caption

We were using a template for our test case design document, and suddenly our management thought of updating it.

After every table, we have a line "Table xx: Steps for `Test Case` xx". This `Test Case` is a caption, and for every test case, the number gets incremented.

Our management decided to change this `Test Case` to `TC`.

I fear that we will have to manually replace every "Test Case" with "TC". Is there any way I can modify this Caption Text throughout the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Find and Replace as Garrulinae suggested but set the style to "Caption."

**More >>** > **Format** > **Style...** > **Caption** > **OK** > **Replace All**

This will only replace text in captions (provided captions are the only text with the Caption style, typically a good assumption).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Find and Replace feature for this.

On the Home tab of the ribbon, click Replace (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) to bring up the Find and Replace dialog.

In the Find field, enter `Test Case`. In the Replace field, enter `TC`.

Now, you can either:

- Click Find Next, then check the text that it finds and click Replace. Repeat this for each instance, or
- Simply click Replace All. Replace All will replace *every* instance of `Test Case` in the document.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way by which I can do it in One click... Coz Manually "Finding and Replacing" is a cumbersome task!

Comment: Yes - 'Replace All'. See above in my answer :) ^^^

Comment: Naaah... Replace all will be hazardous... It replaces everything... Seems that I have to manually do for hundreds of test cases... I was looking a way to edit that caption.

Comment: Or you could search for `Steps for Test Case` and replace it with `Steps for TC`. Then Replace All. That would be less hazardous.